# Pre-set the fts search condition in browse-screen by using screen parameter

Tags: cuba-platform

I want to open a browse-screen with preset fts filter string.

I've a window with a textfield:

```
openWindow('some-browse-screen', WindowManager.OpenType.NEW_TAB, [ftsSearchString: searchTextField.rawValue])
```

And a want to use the input from the textfield as preset value for the browse-screen:

```
@Inject
Filter filter

@Override
void init(Map<String, Object> params) {
    super.init(params)

    if (params.ftsSearchString) {
       //I need a method like that:
       filter.ftsFilterInput.setSearchParam(params.ftsSearchString)
    }
}
```

What possibilities do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a "FTS condition" and make the filter default for this screen, you can pre-set the value for the condition parameter in the same way as for any other condition: by finding the parameter name in filter's UI and using `setParamValue()` in the code:

```java
public class CustomerBrowse extends AbstractLookup {

    @Inject
    private Filter filter;

    @WindowParam
    private String searchTerm;

    @Override
    public void ready() {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            filter.setParamValue("fts56832", searchTerm);
    }
}
```

If you have `defaultMode="fts"`, i.e. the filter is by default in FTS mode with a single parameter, it's more complicated. The component displaying the search term has no public API, so you have to override the `FilterDelegateImpl` in your project and access the `ftsSearchCriteriaField` protected field. I think the simplest way is to override the `setParamValue()` method:

```java
package com.company.sample.web.filter;

import com.haulmont.cuba.gui.components.filter.FilterDelegateImpl;

public class SampleFilterDelegate extends FilterDelegateImpl {

    public static final String FTS_SEARCH_TERM = "_FTS_SEARCH_TERM_";

    @Override
    public void setParamValue(String paramName, Object value) {
        if (paramName.equals(FTS_SEARCH_TERM) && ftsSearchCriteriaField != null) {
            ftsSearchCriteriaField.setValue(value);
            searchBtn.action.actionPerform(); //to run the search
        } else {
            super.setParamValue(paramName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The class must be registered in `web-spring.xml` as prototype bean:

```xml
<bean id="cuba_FilterDelegate" 
      scope="prototype"  
      class="com.company.sample.web.filter.SampleFilterDelegate"/>
```

Then you can set the initial value in the same way as above but passing the predefined parameter name:

```java
public class CustomerBrowse extends AbstractLookup {

    @Inject
    private Filter filter;

    @WindowParam
    private String searchTerm;

    @Override
    public void ready() {
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            filter.setParamValue(SampleFilterDelegate.FTS_SEARCH_TERM, searchTerm);
    }
}
```